# Unity3D follow Sphere player camera rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to get my camera to follow my player (Sphere) when ever it moves around. I have got the camera to follow the player, but when the sphere spins, so do the camera. That is not what i'm looking for. I need the camera to stay put on the sphere and rotate when I turn. This is my code so far:

EDIT: What I'm looking for is something like you see in the vid. where the camera rotate when the sphere is turning, so it's behind it all the time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPAgPQi1l0c

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TransformFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private Transform target;

[SerializeField]
private Vector3 offsetPosition;

[SerializeField]
private Space offsetPositionSpace = Space.Self;

[SerializeField]
private bool lookAt = true;

private void Start()
{
    offsetPosition = new Vector3(-3, -2, 0);
}
private void Update()
{
    Refresh();
}

public void Refresh()
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Missing target ref !", this);

        return;
    }

    // compute position
    if (offsetPositionSpace == Space.Self)
    {
        transform.position = target.TransformPoint(offsetPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = target.position + offsetPosition;
    }

    // compute rotation
    if (lookAt)
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.rotation = target.rotation;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is Camera child of the Player?

Comment: It's not, it's an object.

Comment: You can try making this as child of the player. In hierarchy of course.

Answer (score 2):

Did you write this code yourself?

It simply seems that if `lookat` is true, it will do what you want. If it is false, if will do what you describe.

Just look in the editor and check the 'look at' box.

If you never want to use it you can remove it from the code by removing the `lookat` variable and replacing

```
// compute rotation
if (lookAt)
{
    transform.LookAt(target);
}
else
{
    transform.rotation = target.rotation;
}
```

by

```
// compute rotation
transform.LookAt(target);
```

**EDIT** more explanation:

In your code, you have two options: `lookat` and `offsetPositionSpace`.

Basically, `offsetPositionSpace` can be two values:

- **`Self`** -> The camera will always be behind the player (if you rotate the player, it moves to stay behind
- **`World`** -> The camera will always imitate the player's moves (If the player rotates, the camera won't move

`LookAt` can also have two values

- **true**  -> the camera looks at the player, always
- **false** -> the camera imitate the players rotation (if the player rotates, the camera does the same and stops looking at the player)

Comment: I have borrowed some, but if I do what you suggest, it still do that annoying follow rotation, but it only show the camera from behind the player and does not follow on turns, it just keep rotating when the sphere turns right or left.

Comment: In your code, you have two options: `lookat` and `offsetPositionSpace `. Do you understand what they do? (if not, you should try to understand it). I will add more explaination in my answer. If the behaviour I describe in the answer is not what you need, maybe try to explain the goal better in your question

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the following logic:

Create an empty gameObject:Character, where it will have as childs: Camera, Sphere

when you move, you simply transform the Character, so the Camera and the Sphere transform in the exact same way.

Now, when you want to rotate only the Sphere, but not the camera, just apply your rotation(or anything else), only in the sphere.
To do so, in your script you can pass the Character and the Sphere.
So moving transformations will be applied in on the Character and any custom move, only in the sphere.

Nik